# Asher Yotzar - What type of Bracha is it?

Tags: blessing

What type of Bracha is Asher Yotzar?

Is it a Birchas HaNehenin (you feel relieved after going)?

Birchas HaMitzvos (as it is the conclusion of eating)?

Birchas Hodaa (for our bodies working properly)?

Birchas HaShevach?

(Please include your sources)

Comment: Is there any reason to believe a _b'racha_ of the form of _asher yatzar_ would be a _birkas hamitzva_? I heard a _shi'ur_ once that the context of the text of the prototype for the _b'racha_, where it appears in _maseches Nida_ relates it to giving birth and it may therefore be linked to _shevach_ and especially _hoda'a_.

Comment: Gershon, could you please expand your question to explain why you would think it is anything other than a birchas hodaa?

Comment: Just from its content one might call it a Birchas Shevah. In that way it is more similar to Birchas Hamitzvos.

Comment: I've heard Shevah also.

Comment: Is there really a difference between shevach and hodaah? The rambam for instance seems to group them together as one category (Hil. Brachot 1:4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far this is what I could find.

Shulchan Oruch Orach Chaim Siman 6 Seif 3 says that it is a Birchas Hodaa.

Ritva Pesachim 46 says that it is a Birchas HaShevach.

Minchas Shlomo Chelek 2 Siman 4 Os 28 and Yabia Omer Chelek 9 Siman 3 both say that it is a Birchas HaNehenin.

I heard (although have not found the location yet) that the Chasam Sofer says it is Birchas HaMitzvos.

Answer (score -2):

it's a big mahloket, in any case you can rule out bircat hamitsvot, which we do before the mitsva and not after

neenin also I would rule out, a fruit for example we make the baracha before we eat